# Working with chromedriver in unit-tests, with browser.quit()

Tags: java, unit-testing, selenium-chromedriver

On our project, was decided to use ui-tests as unit-tests. For this we wrote several tests. All of them use one port. Before running tests I execute command from command line (by CI): `nohup Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 & chromedriver --whitelisted-ips --port = 60000` (DISPLAY and PATH, of course, are set in the same session).

If the browser is not closed after tests, it works fine. But we can not do this. It must be closed after each test. If I do:

```
} finally {
   browser.quit();
}
```

first test is ok. But after this, we have hang process `chromedriver`, and used port 60000 (those, I can't run listener: `chromedriver --whitelisted-ips --port = 60000` and so on). And next test failed:

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "{"sessionId":"be69384516355ddaefd5951a10fa3f82","status":13,"value":{"message":"unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally\n  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64)"}}"
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:34493<->127.0.0.1:60000 shut down
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ThreadSafeClientConnManager - Released connection is not reusable.
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Releasing connection [{}->http://localhost:60000][null]
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection - Connection 0.0.0.0:34493<->127.0.0.1:60000 closed
[main] DEBUG org.apache.http.impl.conn.tsccm.ConnPoolByRoute - Notifying no-one, there are no waiting threads
...
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.28.455506 (18f6627e265f442aeec9b6661a49fe819aeeea1f),platform=Linux 3.13.0-45-generic x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information); duration or timeout: 60.03 seconds
Build info: version: '2.10.0', revision: '14416', time: '2011-10-27 23:00:15'
ystem info: os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.13.0-45-generic', java.version: '1.6.0'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:527)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:147)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:113)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:417)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:76)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:120)
    at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.<init>(ChromeDriver.java:98)
    at ru.blogic.lecm.plugin.base.test.executor.DOHTestUIExecutor.execute(DOHTestUIExecutor.java:74)
    at ru.blogic.lecm.plugin.base.test.executor.DOHTestExecutor.testUI(DOHTestExecutor.java:78)
    at ru.blogic.lecm.plugin.base.test.executor.DOHTestExecutor.test(DOHTestExecutor.java:65)
    at ru.blogic.lecm.plugin.base.test.examples.DOHDemoNoUITest.testUtils(DOHDemoNoUITest.java:20)
```

---

I tried to run listener from java code at tests start, like this:

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("export DISPLAY=:2 & export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/ & nohup Xvfb :2 -screen 0 1920x1080x24 & chromedriver --whitelisted-ips --port=60000");
```

and in finally block I try to kill process hardly:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pkill chromedriver");
```

but nothing changed.

Comment: In my tests i dont need to call the driver manually. selenium normally spawns the driver for each browser instance. Is it neseccary to do it manually for your purpose

Comment: Hmmm.. Without calling, first test also failed with error: "unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally". May be reason in somthing else. I'll try to look in this direction. Thank you

Comment: But you set the driver location so selenium can find it? like 'System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverLoc.getPath());'

Comment: I set location, but using builder of ChromeDriverService. Like this: .usingChromeDriverExecutable(new File(chromedriverPath)). It not similar, as I can see? Now I'll try to check with this variant, thanks

Comment: This possibility should also work, yes. Also make sure the driver and chrome version fit, otherwize it leads to weird exceptions as you have. If he can not find the driver it normally gives you a good error message like "No driver found"